# Angular11 html in Struts 1.3 project can't find resources

Tags: angular, struts-1

I want to integrate a new Angular 11 project into an old, legacy Struts 1.3 project.  I have my Angular in one folder and the `package.json` is set up so that the build files are put into the `/webapp` directory with the rest of the Struts files:

```
+--src  
| +-- java  
| +-- ui (Angular files)  
| +-- webapp (Struts)   
| | +-- angular build files  
| | +--web-inf (Struts public files)
```

I link to my angular static html with an action link on a JSP page:

```
<html:link action="ConfigurationDataSetup.do">
```

My `struts-config.xml` has a matching action:

```
<action
    path="/ConfigurationDataSetup"
    type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
    name="ConfigurationDataSetup"
    parameter="/angular/configurationDataSetup.html">
</action>
```

When I serve the project on a local WebLogic server, I get 404 errors indicating the project can't find the rest of my static angular resources.  I think because for some reason it is looking for them at the root of the project:

```
GET http://localhost:7001/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:7001/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:7001/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:7001/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:7001/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I access the project via `localhost:7001/ScoreReportsWorkbench`.
This is the URL that serves my login page.

Any ideas why I can't access these files?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I didn't have a definition in my tiles-defs.xml.  I created a definition:

```
<definition name="configurationDataSetup.layout" extends="base.layout">
        <put name="pageName"  value="ConfigurationDataSetup" />
        <put name="body"   value="/angular/configurationDataSetup.html" />
</definition>
```

This was referenced in my `struts-config.xml`:

```
<action forward="configurationDataSetup.layout" path="/ConfigurationDataSetup" />
```

I also had to include the script and style references in my `base.layout` file so that the webapp could load these resources, since the tile definition just imports the HTML.